# Count the number of occurrences of each article number in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of occurrences of each article number in my table. My table has the following structure:

```
|customerNumber|OrderNumber|ArticleNumber|
|1|1|1|    
|2|2|2|    
|3|3|4|    
|1|4|3|    
|3|3|2|    
|4|5|2| 
|5|6|4|
```

Expected Outcome:

```
|ArticleNumber|NumberOfOrders|
|1|1|
|2|3|
|3|1|
|4|2|
```

How can I do it? ( I got no idea atm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count(fieldName)` from `tablename` syntax to achieve your requirement.

So now, the code can be,

```
select ArticleNumber,count(NumberOfOrders) as NumberOfOrders from 
tableName  group by ArticleNumber
```

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner it will work..as per your given question ....may be you are making any mistake in your query and architecture ......look that again

Comment: @ what is the result have you got ? what do you need ? give some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

you need to count ArticleNumber then use below query

`SELECT ArticleNumber,COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOrders FROM your_table group by ArticleNumber`